# group of order $pq^n$ is solvable?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

If $p<q$ be primes and $n \geq 0$ integer. If $G$ is a group such that its order is $pq^n$, then $G$ is solvable.

I tried to use Sylows theorem to find number of Sylows subgroups but I stuck with finding $n_q$. Is my strategy right or need to change it?

Thanks

Comment: You will need normal subgroups and the only way Sylow gives you normal subgroups is when there's a unique $p$-Sylow or $q$-Sylow, but this need not be the case (consider $G=S_4$). This statement requires some slightly more sophisticated methods.

Comment: $S_4$ does not satisfy the hypothesis. Only the larger prime is allowed to have a non-trivial exponent.

Comment: @verret: $S_4$ is solvable. Both primes are allowed to have arbitrary exponents. It is Burnside's theorem (it is not trivial).

Comment: I'm talking about the hypothesis of the actual question, which does not mention Burnside's Theorem... If $S_4$ has order $pq^n$, then we must have $p=n=3$ and $q=2$, but this contradicts $p<q$...

Comment: @verret: I guess the problem is from Hungerford. The book, indeed, does not mention the theorem. But the theorem still exists and is correct although much less trivial than the problem. So the assumption $p<q$ is not necessary. Your comment is correct, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Burnside's theorem any group of order $p^kq^m$ where $p,q$ are prime is solvable https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_theorem

Without the theorem. The number of Sylow $q$-subgroups should divide $p$ and is $\equiv 1\mod q$. Since $p<q$ it is only possible if there is one Sylow $q$-subgroup which is normal and nilpotent. The quotient group is cyclic of order $p$ so the group is solvable.